# Prevent booting into Desktop GUI by default on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, remote-desktop, xserver

I want to install Ubuntu Desktop in my remote Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I want to access the same from my local machine using Xserver xming and use the desktop feature.

But I want the Ubuntu server to boot into just terminal and remain Headless.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in your `/etc/default/grub` file to "text" value. Then run `update-grub`.

Comment: Thanks @nullop. Will I be able to run/start desktop from there?

Comment: To run a graphical desktop after logging in via console you can start lightdm service by running `sudo service lightdm start`, or just run `startx` script.